# in CheckOut form have states show as abbreviations not full state name

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm running Magento 1.9 and I have Googled and researched for a simple answer to this but no luck. I tried this option but does not work. > https://somoza.be/magento/checkout-state-abbreviations-in-magento/

Other options I've found do not explain where the files are located that I need to alter. I'm 3 moths into Magento.

Thank you